# Recaptcha and Search Indexing

Tags: search, indexing, recaptcha

Can you use Google's recaptcha on a site with a large number of pages and still allow it to be crawled by friendly search indexing bots (like Google, etc)?

In short, some bot good, some bot bad.. block only bad bot.

This seems like an obvious question one should consider but I can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why so? I'm a developer trying to implement bot protection on a website and this is a technical consideration.